# Exchange - OnPremises - Send-on-behalf for public folders behave as Send-As

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, send

We have a weird problem that has started occuring.

Mail-enabled public folders configured as Send-on-behalf-of has started behaving as if they are configured with Send-AS for users.

We have certain restrictions inhouse to NOT camouflage our users, and it is therefore against our policy to anonymize users for all public folders.

For some reason, Send-on-behalf-of rights are behaving as if there was only SEND AS configured, and all users sending mail become anonymous, which is not desirable.

I am unable to find any setting or attribute online that could have caused this.

The servers are on-premise Exhchange 2019 servers.

Anyone know what could cause this behaviour?

No users are added to the SEND AS lists, only SEND-ON-BEHALF-OF-LIST in Exchange

Comment: Might be better asking this on ServerFault sister community.  You have your server fully patched Windows Updates and the latest CU for Exchange installed? Should be a way to check Exchange AD attribute security to the object to ensure a default has not been overridden somehow at that level or a group/principal tied to them. I have scripts that ran Public Folder Exchange 2010 never worked with them on Exchange 2019 and they changed that I think. I vaguely recall something with this with Exchange 2010 but probably not applicable to Public Folders on Exchange 2019 but SF may be a better route.

Comment: In case it helps though, play with this and see what you come up with, I was exporting to csv so adjust accordingly if it even helps any with Exchange 2019 public folders: https://pastebin.com/kjVMqTJV as https://i.imgur.com/fmtwEMw.png